# Redirect issue with admin login using ActiveAdmin in rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication, devise, activeadmin

I'm using `devise` and `activeadmin`.

When I log in to my app as an Admin (`http://localhost:3000/users/admin`) the app redirects me to to the `http://localhost:3000/users/sign_in` page.

So basically I have to login at some user to be able to log in as Admin. Which is really inconvenient.

this is my `application_controller.rb`

```
 class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
       protect_from_forgery prepend: true, with: :exception

       before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:index]

      def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
        user_path(resource)
      end

      def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
        user_path(resource)
      end


  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

    protected

    def configure_permitted_parameters
     devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:username, :email, :password, :password_confirmation])
     devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_in, keys: [:login, :password, :password_confirmation])
     devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:account_update, keys: [:username, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :current_password])
    end


end
```

I have added this chunk of code to the controller with out any luck.

```
before_action :whois, if: :devise_controller?


def whois
 if user.admin?
   def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
     admin_dashboard_path
   end
 else
   def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
     user_path(resource)
   end

   def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
     user_path(resource)
   end
 end
end
```

Here my routes

```
  devise_for :users
  devise_for :admin_users, ActiveAdmin::Devise.config
  ActiveAdmin.routes(self)



  resources :overviews
  resources :users

  root 'overviews#index'
```

Can anyone help me with this, please?

Comment: could you post the parts of `routes.rb` that contains devise and active admin config?

Comment: @mrzasa I added the routes.rb

Answer (score 0):

In the initializer active_admin.rb - try this

```
config.authentication_method = false
```